# laravel 5 subdomain not working in xampp

Tags: php, laravel-5, xampp

I am developing in xampp as host in my local. The project runs on 
`php artisan serve` and it can be access at `http://localhost:8000`

Now I want to create a subdomain but in my case it didn't work. I would like to run it in `http://dummyresort.localhost:8000` but it redirected to homepage.

This is my route.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'dummyresort.localhost:8000'], function()
{

    Route::get('/resort/dummyresort', 'FrontendController@dummyresort');
});
```

and this is the `php artisan route:list`
`dummyresort.localhost:8000 | GET|HEAD                       | resort/dummyresort                                           |      | App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@dummyresort  | web`

any ideas about my case?

I also create a virtual host in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/compass/compass"
    ServerName localhost:8000
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You will need to update you host file for new redirection, if you are on windows. For other OS i have no idea. Also it would be great if you can use virtual host.

Comment: You have to create virtual host in your server.

Comment: Do you have any idea for multiple apps with one Laravel codebase using subdomain routing on xampp for macos?

Answer (score 0):

Make a virtual host and try again

Comment: can you show me how to deal with it? I have updated my question

Comment: and in xampp vhostconfig add your server

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have found and it's working

Update Locally : ....\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/public"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost
    <Directory "E:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/public">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then Try this routing

```
Route::group([
    'domain'    => '{office_name}.localhost'
],function(){
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return 'I AM OFFICE OWNER';
    });
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'I AM SITE VISITOR';
});
```

Run with `php artisan serv`

Comment: hhahahaha okay so after 7 months, i am trying to upvote my own post :p